# Architecture Design MVC Site - Help In Design

Tags: web-services, asp.net-mvc-4, azure, architecture

I don't know if this is relevant for Stackoverflow, if its not suitable my sincere apology...

I got a new project that i'm working on right now and I really could use the help of a programmer that familiar with architecture software design in MVC model (**MVC 4 asp.net**).

I have a WebSerivce that does manipulation on files and return them, I want to create a website that support the upload files(of the user) send to WS and return them to the user( the user will be able to download the files after the manipulation of the WS)

**Main goal scenario:**

1.User enter the site.

2.User upload files.

3.The files send to a WebService that does manipulation on the files and return them to the site(with information about his manipulation on each file).

4.User see statistics on the files and capable to download them.

**Additional info:**
I have an Azure cloud that i can use for storing the files and mange a data tables(SQL) and etc..

A very simmilar project is :

[www.VirusTotal.com](http://www.virustotal.com)

The only diffrent is that they not returning new file only scan the file with 50+ Anti Viruses, my web service scanning the files and than remove the evil code inside of the files and return the "new" files to the user.

Thank You.

Comment: what questions do you have?

Comment: How to design my project ? controller wise..
and how can i send files to the WS with one function of controller and
get answer (from WS) to a new view?
last question is does it help to create a new controller or can i use the default controller "homecontroller" i think its called...